# can't include <X11/Xft/Xft.h> when compiling nana library, no such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, nana

I'm trying to install the [nana C++ library](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-docs/wiki/Installation) in Ubuntu 16.04.

I downloaded and unzipped it into the directory with my *helloworld* file, and went to the directory with the makefile; *nana/build/makefile*, and typed `make` but got the error

> X11/Xft/Xft.h: no such file or directory

I checked */usr/include/X11* and yeah, it's not there. Googling has not helped figure out hot to install Xft. How do I do it? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: IIRC: Wherever you did install it to, pass that with `-L` to your compiler.

Comment: Do you mean `make -L`? Just tried it and it has the same error. Looks like a library is missing.

Answer (score 20):

This header seems to be in `libxft-dev` package. Install it with your package manager. If it is apt, try:

```
sudo apt install libxft-dev
```